# Convergence of bound integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove or disprove:
>   Given $f(x)$ a continuous function in $(0,1]$, and exists $M$ such that
>   $$\left|\int_x^1 f(t)~\mathrm{d}t \right| \le M$$
>   for every $0\lt x \lt 1$, then $$\int_0^1 f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$$ converges.

**My try:**

By the Cauchy rule for integral convergence:

$\int_0^1 f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$ converges iff

for every $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that every $s,r \in (0,\delta)$, $s>r$ : 
$$\left|\int_r^s f(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right|<\epsilon$$

So, the formulation of the question is a bit "fishy", and my intuition tells me that the argument is false.

I tried to think about counter example that meets all the conditions, but cannot find one.

Is my intuition right? If so, can you give me a hint for such example?

Comment: @ Adam Hughes there are many bounded continuous functions that do not have a limit. Take $\sin(1/x)$ for example. By the way, the derivative of this function can be a counterexample for the argument in question.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval sorry, I meant to delete sooner, I had thought I had read a "monotone" clause, which would have given uniform continuity, after rereading that's not the case.

Comment: that was the first function i tried to use. but not it's derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take any $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded and differentiable, but does not have a limit at $0$, and differentiate it.